# Mac Mini High Sierra Res Resolution issue

Tags: mac, resolution, vlc-media-player, macos-highsierra

I have a Mac Mini running onHigh Sierra that I'm using as a media PC (running on a generic Sansui TV)
I'm having a resolution switching issue.

Problem I have is that if/when the Mac starts before the TV, VLC launches and then when the TV fires up, VLC is playing in the top left 80% of the screen, so I would need to then remote in (using anydesk) and manually full screen it.

I am assuming that the Mac doesn't detect the display while it is off and defaults to a higher resolution, then when the screen is detected, the mac adjusts its resolution to the TV native res (1366x768)

I have the Mac set to auto start at a certain time, Launch VLC and start a playlist full screen. then shut down at a certain time.

I also have the TV set to start at a certain time (still trying to get it to start at the correct time, before the mac) and then it shuts itself off after a while of "no signal"

Is there any way to force the mac permanently to one resolution only? Maybe delete all other resolutions in the Plist or something.
or possibly make a script that can check when the resolution changes to then launch VLC so VLC launching is delayed... or even just delay the launch of VLC?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up an Automator Application, which you can then add as a login item.
Set a pause to give your TV time to start up, followed by launching VLC.

[image]

If the Mac can't detect any display, it's unlikely you can lock it to a given resolution beforehand, so I think you'll have to wait until the display is available. VLC isn't smart enough to detect the resolution change, but the Mac should be.

Comment: would VLC start and then auto run the playlist at full screen, or should I just set the automator to run the playlist file?

Comment: You'd have to load & play the playlist, same as you do now.

Comment: so I have the .m3u running as a login item. that in tern launches VLC, so not sure how to set the automator to launch the file and not just the VLC application

Comment: It's not something i'm familiar with, but see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281447/applescript-to-play-videos-in-vlc